# StackExchange.Redis - disable use of EVALSHA?

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

On stopping and restarting the Redis server, sending something through Redis throws the following error: "StackExchange.Redis.RedisServerException: NOSCRIPT No matching script. Please use EVAL."

My understanding is that this error happens when the server does not remember the script with the SHA1 digest. I am guessing the server removes the cached scripts on restart -  how should this be handled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The library detects this error internally and flushes the local cache of known-good scripts, so the library will self-heal from this, and the next time the script is invoked it will issue a `SCRIPT LOAD` automatically. If you are using the `*Async` API it does not re-issue this automatically, because it would be impossible to understand what the caller wants to happen and whether there are related commands already in flight. However, when using the non-`*Async` API, it knows that this isn't an issue, so it automatically re-issues the command for you without presenting the error.

Restarting a redis server is a fairly rare event, but: I suspect it could reasonably be changed to flush the script cache upon disconnect.

---

Update: I now [track changes to the run-id](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/commit/a335a78a097084cda731cf548bd93edd542fb776), which uniquely identifies a server run (thus restart). If this changes, the script cache is flushed.

Comment: Yeah, I think you should have the ability to clear the cache on the client when the server restarts. I'll open an issue for this on GitHub, would you be able to take a look into this sometime soon?

Comment: @Abhishek yes, I think so. Note that we don't necessarily know that the server has restarted (although I might be able to check the run-id on up-level servers) - all we can guarantee to detect is a disconnect

Comment: @MarcGravell We also use Async api, from the pr you have posted, you flush the scripts but do you reload them ? We are having an issue that the library does not reload the script after flushing it and we need to handle it by forcing it to reload explicitly on our side as a workaround solution.

Comment: @fiskra `FlushScriptCache` doesn't flush the scripts in redis; it simply flushes what it knows *in the client*, i.e. it should now automatically do a `SCRIPT LOAD` the next time you use a script, because it assumes it isn't on the server